# Trouble understanding YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am new to YAML and I would like to understand the following piece of a .yaml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    influxdb:
        image: influxdb:alpine
        environment:
            INFLUXDB_DB: ft_services
            INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: admin
            INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
        volumes:
            - datainfluxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
```

As far as I know, there are 3 types of data that can be used in a .yaml file: scalars, sequences and mappings. For example, `version: "3.7"` is a scalar. But I am not sure what the following are:

```
volumes:
            - datainfluxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

```
environment:
            INFLUXDB_DB: ft_services
            INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: admin
            INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

I don't really understand what type of data are these and how do they work, can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Additionally to the answers below, may I recommend my [short YAML tutorial](https://www.yaml.info/learn/index.html)? It goes through some typical examples. Feedback welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lists

example

```
volumes:
   - data: /var/lib
     other-field: "example"
   - data: /etc
```

Each indented line beginning with an `-` above is the beginning of a *List Item*. There is two items in the list in the example and the whole list is named `volumes`. The example is a List of Maps, but also List of Scalars is valid.

### Maps

example

```
environment:
    INFLUXDB_DB: ft_services
    INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: admin
    INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

as you wrote, this is a Map with Key-Value pairs and the whole Map is named `environment`.

### Scalars

As you wrote there is also scalars of various types. A value within quotes like `"3.7"` is a `string`.

Comment: `Lists` - the provided example is actually `List of Maps`, which I think should be present as very popular in yaml, but as a separate example

Answer (score 2):

> **But I am not sure what the following are:**

- **List of maps**:

  ```
  volumes:
    - datainfluxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
  ```

  Equal json:

  ```
  {
    "volumes": [
      {"datainfluxdb": "/var/lib/influxdb"}
    ]
  }
  ```
- **Map**:

  ```
  environment:
    INFLUXDB_DB: ft_services
    INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: admin
    INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
  ```

  Equal json:

  ```
  {
    "environment": {
      "INFLUXDB_DB": "ft_services",
      "INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER": "admin",
      "INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD": "admin"
    }
  }
  ```
- And not mentioned in your question, but a simple **List of strings**

  ```
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  ```

  Equal json:

  ```
  {
    "accessModes": [
      "ReadWriteOnce"
    ]
  }
  ```

These 3 are the most frequently seen in Kubernetes.

In my opinion, in the beginning, YAML gets the most confusing when you have nested structures. For easier understanding, I suggest using smth like https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json to convert to JSON, which has more explicit structures syntax.